# Unable to access jQuery from my views on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg

I need to access jquery from my views, and I can't figure out how to make rails inject it into the pages.  I'm testing for having jquery with the following code:

```
=render 'nav'
:javascript
  if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
  } else {
    alert("JQuery undefined");
  }
```

It's always been "jquery undefined".

I've tried many things including adding `jquery-rails` to the Gemfile. Running `yarn add jquery`.

I tried modifying `config/webpack/environment.js` to be like this:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')

// Add an additional plugin of your choosing : ProvidePlugin
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    JQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.Tether': "tether",
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'], // for Bootstrap 4
  })
)

const envConfig = module.exports = environment
const aliasConfig = module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    }
  }
}


module.exports = merge(envConfig.toWebpackConfig(), aliasConfig)
```

I added references to jquery also under `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Here is `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
%html
  %head
    %title Imagehost
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    %meta{"name"=>"viewport", "content"=>"width=device-width", "initial-scale"=>"1", "shrink-to-fit"=>"no"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  %body
    = yield
```

There are no error messages on the console.

Comment: Just answered a similar question (jquery plus jquery-ui) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555708/rails-6-how-to-add-jquery-ui-through-webpacker

Comment: I made some updates to my answer - check it out if you still need this

Answer (score 0):

The `ProvidePlugin` as you've configured it will require jQuery (when missing) for legacy scripts bundled by Webpack. It does not expose jQuery to the global scope, which explains why it is undefined in your HAML template.

There are a number of ways you can accomplish this, though I'd recommend extending your Webpack configuration using the [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) for jQuery. The expose-loader "exposes" variables to the global scope from Webpack.

```
yarn add expose-loader
```

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')


environment.loaders.prepend('jquery', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: 'jQuery'
  },{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: '$'
  }]
})
```

With the above config added, you should be able to access `window.$` and `window.jQuery` from your HAML templates.