# Import images of an npm package with Webpacker and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, webpacker

I'm trying to install the package [lightslider](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider) with `yarn` and `webpacker`.

Here's what I did so far :

```
yarn add lightslider
```

```
// app/webpacker/packs/application.js

require('lightslider');
```

```
// app/webpacker/src/application.scss

@import '~lightslider/dist/css/lightslider.min';
```

However, the Webpack compilation fails because of the following error :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/controls.png'
```

which is an image that is required by lightslider to work properly, and is located in `node_modules/lightslider/dist/img/controls.png` :

```
// node_modules/lightslider/dist/css/lightslider.css

.lSAction > a {
    width: 32px;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url('../img/controls.png');
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: -16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0s;
}
```

How can I import this image in my pack so that lightslider will find it ?

Comment: I haven't tried lightslider, but I recently successfully added jquery ui from jquery-ui-dist package. See if the following is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580434/908842

Comment: Please include what versions of Rails, webpackER, and @rails/webpacker you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the WebpackER docs: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/76b491750993fada8b0b0cc2546dfcfbc4aaae13/docs/css.md#resolve-url-loader

> Since Sass/libsass does not provide url rewriting, all linked assets must be relative to the output. Add the missing url rewriting using the resolve-url-loader. Place it directly after the sass-loader in the loader chain.

```js
// webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// resolve-url-loader must be used before sass-loader
environment.loaders.get('sass').use.splice(-1, 0, {
  loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
});
```

I was able to reproduce/fix the issue you described without/with the modification above using `@rails/webpacker@4.0.7` and `resolve-url-loader@3.1.0`.