# How do you get JQuery to work with Rails 6 and Webpacker 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, coffeescript

I really cant believe that getting JQuery to work with Rails 6 and Webpacker 6 can be so hard.

Suggestions in [Rails 6: How to add jquery-ui through webpacker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555708/rails-6-how-to-add-jquery-ui-through-webpacker) don't appear to have worked but hard to know if it is the same code stack.

I am using Rails 6.1 and a pre-release version of Webpacker 6.0 to get Heroku to play nicely. Oh, and most of my "Javascript" is in .coffee files.

I even tried renaming application.js to application.coffee and reformatting but that didnt work either.

My Gemfile has

```
gem 'webpacker', '~> 6.0.0.beta.6'
```

I have done the following"

```
yarn add jquery jquery-ui-dist jquery-blockui
```

Then in webpacker 6 style configured as follows:

```
# config/webpacker/base.js
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const customConfig = require('./custom')

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig)
```

```
# config/webpacker/custom.js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jquery_ui: 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
# code/app/packs/entrypoints/application.js

global.$ = require("jquery")
require("jquery") // Don't really need to require this...
require("jquery-ui")
require("jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui")
```

This is all a mish-mash of attempts from a number of sources including this post - [Rails 6: How to add jquery-ui through webpacker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555708/rails-6-how-to-add-jquery-ui-through-webpacker), https://github.com/rails/webpacker and others.

By the way, I am trying to migrate my Coffescript from Rails 5 and so this makes extensive use of the JQuery $ global.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the final solution with assistance from mechnicov for me was, as suggested by him:

```
// config/webpack/base.js

const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const customConfig = require('./custom')

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig)
```

```
// config/webpack/custom.js

const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    // Eliminate CORS issue
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000
    }
}
```

```
# app/packs/entrypoints/application.js

// Make jQuery available everywhere
global.$ = require('jquery'), require('jquery-ui'), require('jquery-blockui')
...
```

I dont know if this is the most elegant solution (are the resolve, plugins and application.js line all necessary?), but it works.

BTW also required ensuring that both the webpacker gem and the corresponding yarn module were version 6.0.0.beta.6 (see https://github.com/rails/webpacker)

```
# Gemfile

gem 'webpacker', '6.0.0.beta.6'
```

```
$ yarn add @rails/webpacker@6.0.0-beta.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly add JQuery to project:

```
yarn add jquery
```

Then add to webpack plugins in `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.
  plugins.
  append(
    'Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  )
```

That's it

Well in webpacker 6.0 you can do use one of ways:

1. Directly update `config/webpack/base.js`:

```
const { webpackConfig } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

webpackConfig.
  plugins.
  push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  )

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

2. Use custom config and merge it to base:

```js
// config/webpack/base.js

const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const customConfig = require('./custom')

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig)
```

```js
// config/webpack/custom.js

const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that seems so simple. The problem I have is that the environment.js file does not exist under Webpacker 6.0, or so I understand. Instead it uses base.js as I have shown in my question. 

It is also my understanding that the syntax you have pasted is replaced by custom.js in which I have tried multiple combinations but now have:

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }
    }
}

Comment: Thanks very much mechnicov. That pretty much solved the issue although I dont understand why this isnt better documented anywhere.
The only other thing I appeared to have to do was to update my application.js to have:
global.$ = require('jquery'), require('jquery-ui'), require('jquery-blockui')
I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the "updated" answer in the given article.

https://gorails.com/forum/install-bootstrap-with-webpack-with-rails-6-beta

Comment: Thanks. But same issue with your answer as with mechnicov below - the discussion does not relate to a Webpacker 6.0 solution