# Ruby-on-Rails-6: Dynamic Cascading Dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I've gone through several websites and resources and I can't seem to get dynamic cascading dropdown to work following guides or anything. One common theme I see is that all guides and help are for Rails 5 or older and I'm using Rails 6, so not sure if 6 isn't compatible with those solutions.

I have the following models:

**Organization**

```
  class Organization < ApplicationRecord

      has_many :org_ratings, dependent: :destroy

  end
```

**OrgRating**

```
class OrgRating < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :organization

end
```

Then I have a form for "RATING" which tracks the OrgRating and Organization from the models above.

```
<%= form_with(model: rating, local: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="col-6">
    <%= f.collection_select :organization_id, Organization.order(:name), :id, :name,{},{ class: "custom-select" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :rating_id, Organization.order(:name), :org_ratings, :name, :id, :rating, {},{ class: "custom-select" } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I followed this tutorial (http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) and this was the JS file i created (I read that coffee is not supported in Rails 6 and web packer plays nice with JS)

**app/javascript/packs/rating.js**

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('#rating_rating_id').parent().hide();
  ratings = $('#rating_rating_id').html();
  return $('#rating_organization_id').change(function() {
    organization = $('#rating_organization_id :selected').text();
    escaped_organization = organization.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(ratings).filter(`optgroup[label='${escaped_organization}']`).html();
    if (options) {
      $('#rating_rating_id').html(options);
      return $('#rating_rating_id').parent().show();
    } else {
      $('#rating_rating_id').empty();
      return $('#rating_rating_id').parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks for any direction and apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I think more information is required, especially how it does not work, I mean, how it fails against your expectation and/or any error messages in Console etc, as well as what you have tried so far and found how they did not work.

One potential issue is jQuery in Rails 6 in combination with Webpacker. See this question and links inside, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66898873/3577922

Comment: Thank you Masa, my apologies for not being clear on what isn't working. I'm able to show the drop down Organization (header) and then A, B, C (options) below. 

However the part that wasn't working was, when selecting the organization (first drop down) have the second drop down only list the A, B, C  based on the selection from the first. 

I will try to read through the example you shared and hopefully it will assist me. 
Really appreciate your help and will report any updates. :)

Comment: Today I posted an answer to a similar question (by myself), which is based on the same resource as in your case. It may be of some help? To add, make sure jQuery is working in your Rails 6 environment. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68274550/3577922

Comment: It's taking me a bit longer to digest this than I expected.

Comment: The guide mentions: 
- config/webpack/environment.js (i have this code:)
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")
environment.plugins.append("Provide",
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: 'jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery',
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
})
)
module.exports = environment

I don't have these
- config/webpack/base.js 
- config/webpack/base.js 
- config/webpack/custom.js (assuming i'd create this one)

My config before: Rails: 6.0.3.4 Ruby: 2.7.2p137 WebPacker: 4.3.0 JQuery: 3.5.1